# VERY stuck on 'No Route Matches error'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and keep getting the following error message:

```
ActionController::RoutingError in Users#index 

"No route matches {:action=>"following", :controller=>"users"}"

Showing /app/views/layouts/_navbar.html.erb......where line #19 raised:

Extracted source (around line #19):
16: </td>
17:                 </div>
18:        
19:                 <div id="secondlink"><td class="rite"><li><% if signed_in? %><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li><li><%= link_to "watching", following_user_path(@user)%></li><li><%= link_to "Users", users_path %></li><li><%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, :method => :delete %>
20:       <% else %>
21: <%= link_to "Sign in", signin_path %></li><% end %>
22:
```

This routing error occurs when I click on the link (in my navbar) to display a full list of paginated Users"

My routes.rb file has the following in it:

```
 Mvp::Application.routes.draw do
   resources :users do
    member do
      get :following, :followers
    end
   end
```

"Following" action in UsersController:

```
def following
    @title = "Following"
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.following.paginate(:page => params[:page])
    render 'show_follow'
end
```

Comment: Could you please post the output of `rake routes`?

Comment: Do you get the same error if you access the url directly? Try surfing to `/users/SOME_VALID_USERID/following`

Comment: Yes, can see individual users profile- I have a "Watching" list that paginates the users who I am "following", and the error occurs only when I click the link "users" to display all the users. ty.

Comment: Try adding a debug output for the `@user` variable - maybe something is wrong there. `<%= debug @user %>. This should show a user object.

Comment: This is what  is in the top Nav bar...<%= link_to "Users", users_path%>..Where would I put a debug output? Thanks!

Comment: Just anywhere in the view, it does not really matter.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot say for sure, but my first guess is that in the following

```
<%= link_to "watching", following_user_path(@user)%>
```

The variable `@user` is nil. I don't know why it is nil, but if it were nil this is the error you would get.

Comment: I think this is right. Shouldn't it be `current_user` instead? Or am I misunderstanding the purpose of that link?

Comment: Hmm...so I can access the users I'm following in my "Watching" page but can't access all users in the user index page (where the error is)

Comment: You probably can, but you have to set it the appropriate variables in the #index method. What, exactly, are you trying to display on the index page?

Comment: Now that I look at it again, I think @pjmorse is on the right track. The error appears to occur in the link next to the "Profile" link, which I presume links to the Profile for current_user. This leads me to believe that what you need to do is change `@user` to `current_user`.

Comment: Works. :))) Thanks for all the effort guys!

Comment: You're welcome. Remember to check Dave's answer as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The `rake routes` outputs

```
following_user GET    /users/:id/following(.:format) users#following
followers_user GET    /users/:id/followers(.:format) users#followers
         users GET    /users(.:format)               users#index
               POST   /users(.:format)               users#create
      new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)           users#new
     edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)      users#edit
          user GET    /users/:id(.:format)           users#show
               PUT    /users/:id(.:format)           users#update
               DELETE /users/:id(.:format)           users#destroy
```

So you got your route - controller mapping defined.

Next things to check:

- do you have `following` action in your `UsersController` defined
- are you requesting a server response with a `GET` method

Comment: following action in UsersController is: